Why can't I open a submenu?
PROBLEM
I wanted to customize my VSCode experience and found this settings.json file here. After downloading the APC extension everything appeared to be perfect. But after reenabling the menubar to always show:
{
  // original line
  "window.menuBarVisibility": "toggle",
  // new line
  "window.menuBarVisibility": "visible",
}

The editor is somehow bugged and you cannot open any submenu in the menubar.
DIFFICULTIES
I am not a CSS expert and by no means am I an APC expert.
MY TRIES
I did some digging and found the exact line which caused this behavior (after commenting it out the problem was gone so I am assuming it is the problem):
{
  "apc.stylesheet": {
    ".monaco-menu": "backdrop-filter:blur(10px) !important"

    // The original line also included a background color which 
    // isn't the problem as it persists after removing the it:
    //".monaco-menu": "background:#202020bb !important; backdrop-filter:blur(10px) !important",
  }
}

I know what this line does (it blurs everything behind the menu), but unfortunatly, as stated above, I am no expert and have no idea what may be the problem with this line and how to fix it.
REPRODUCE
To reproduce this problem just follow these steps:

Create a new user-profile inside VSCode (or use your exsisting one, but may have unexpected behavior)
Install The Apc Customize UI++ Extension
Open the settings.json file
Add the above code snippet and save
Now try to go to "File -> Preferences" (you won't be able to open the preferences submenu)


Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format. Don't add tags.

Can you provide screenshots? before and after?

Not really, because whats there to show? nothing happens when i click it
